# Deploying Vue app to Heroku, cannot find module shelljs

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a vue template to our heroku instance. I have setup the procfile to call the right build script but am getting this.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
```

**And the logs from it are:**

```
2017-10-19T18:14:59.663986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-19T18:15:05.595940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2017-10-19T18:15:13.354029+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-19T18:15:13.354061+00:00 app[web.1]: > genesisui-vue@1.8.4 dev /app
2017-10-19T18:15:13.354061+00:00 app[web.1]: > node build/dev-server.js
2017-10-19T18:15:13.354062+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882843+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:529
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882854+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882855+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882855+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882856+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882857+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882858+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882860+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/check-versions.js:4:13)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882860+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882861+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882861+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.882863+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
2017-10-19T18:15:13.894056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-10-19T18:15:13.894488+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2017-10-19T18:15:13.896140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! genesisui-vue@1.8.4 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
2017-10-19T18:15:13.896314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-10-19T18:15:13.896580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-10-19T18:15:13.896777+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the genesisui-vue@1.8.4 dev script.
2017-10-19T18:15:13.896948+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-10-19T18:15:15.163061+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-19T18:15:15.166845+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-10-19T18:15:15.166959+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-10-19T18_15_13_902Z-debug.log
2017-10-19T18:15:15.282631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-10-19T18:15:15.299772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Any leads would be very grateful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. npm install shelljs --save
2. git commit - m “your comment”
3. git push -u origin master
4. git push heroku master

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work. Any other ideas.